# I want product popup plugin in wordpress it should not be of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I want a wordpress free version plugin in which i can popup different products.
I am sending you a link for example.
[In these link when u will click on model name popup will open i want that type of plugin]

http://herculesdla.com/hercules-deadline-anchors

Answer (score 0):

If your a little bit knowledgeable on WP_Query coding you can use [WDES Responsive Popup](http://4nton.com/product/wdes-responsive-popup/) plugin for the product popup. This is a free plugin just click download in the download button.

Check the examples and documentations for the better understanding.